# Cannot create the right formula in RStudio

Tags: r

```
y<-function(x){
  (1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(^(-1/2)x^2))

  return (x)
}
```

I am trying to create [this](http://prntscr.com/l69b2p) formula on R

Comment: `exp(-1/2*x^2)`.

Comment: `x = 1; 1/sqrt(2* pi) * exp(-1/2*x^2)`
[1] 0.2419707

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, also remove `return(x)` from the function. Btw., you could (should) just do `dnorm(x)`, since your formula is the density of a standard normal distribution and `dnorm` handles extreme inputs more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exp() is already e^, so exp(^(-1/2)*x^2)) should be exp(-1/2*x^2)